# Cycles toon shading and regular shading in same image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I am new to Blender and I want to use cycles to render a scene that has both diffuse and glossy textures that have smooth lighting, and a toon shaded object that only has bands of solid color but is affected by the same light sources.

Is there a way to do this? I tried using the Toon BSDF shader but that doesn't provide solid blocks of color.

I am trying to render an indoor dimly lit scene, which seems to be giving me extra problems.

Comment: Hi, try to show your setup (scene) and shaders (nodes) settings...

Answer (score 3):

Combining multiple toon shaders with different size results in a banding effect for sharp light sources. However it will still look smoother when more indirect lighting occurs.

[image]
[image]